# Displaying image from Parse in UIImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift, parse-platform

I am working on an iOS App, and I am trying to display an image that I retrieved from an online backend i.e. Parse.com

I have this so far:

```
var img = UIImage()
let userImageFile = object["image"] as PFFile
userImageFile.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
    (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if !error {
           println("Imaging!")
           img = UIImage(data:imageData)
           self.pic.image = img
        } else {
           print("Nooooo")
        }
}
```

I have already taken the PFObject (using it here as "object"). "pic" is defined as an IBOutlet UIImageView.

Xcode always says "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Is imageData coming back as nil?  Try adding a if statement to make sure imageData isn't nil.  if let actualImageData = imageData { img = UIImage(data:imageData) ...}  Also what line is Xcode crashing on?